# Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type ' (UnsafePointer<Int8>,Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>' and 'Int'

Tags: swift

I am trying to traverse a priority queue using for loop

Test case is like this

```
var i = 2
for item in queue {
    assert(item == i--)
}
```

I have extended my original `PriorityQueue` like this

```
extension PriorityQueue {
    private func getItemsInPriorityOrder() -> [I] {
        if !isSorted {
            isSorted = true
            queue.sortInPlace{
                return ($0 == nil) ? true  :
                       ($1 == nil) ? false :
                            $0.priority > $1.priority
            }
        }
        var items: [I] = []
        for i in 1..<queue.count {
            items.append( queue[i].item)
        }
        return items
    }
}
```

And

```
extension PriorityQueue: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> _PriorityQueueIterator<I> {
        return _PriorityQueueIterator<I>(items: getItemsInPriorityOrder())
    }
}

public struct _PriorityQueueIterator <I> : GeneratorType {
    private let items: [I]
    private var intex = 0

    init(items: [I]){
       self.items = items
    } 

    public mutating func next() -> I? {
       return index  >=  items.count ? nil : items[index++] // this giving the error
     }
}
```

My return statement `return index  >=  items.count ? nil : items[index++]`
is giving the following error

[image: error message]

I didn't declare anything explicitly as of type `Int8`, `Int16`, or `Int32`

Comment: You should get out of the habit of saying `index++` as this language feature will be removed in future versions of Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is named `intex` (notice the typo), so the `index` in the function is referring to a different symbol which happens to be a function named `index`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the problem, my mistake, xcode should give relevant error message

Comment: @OmarFaruqe: Well, Xcode actually gives a correct error message here. In your (wrong) code, `index` refers to the global function `public func index(_: UnsafePointer<Int8>, _: Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>` (as you can see if you command-click on it). Xcode cannot *guess* that you had a typo.